# How should I include javascript in a template in Phoenix 1.5

Tags: webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to include a javascript file that uses chart.js in my phoenix 1.5 project that uses webpack. When I add something like `<script>require('/js/graph').Graph.draw()</script>` in a template, I see the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in browser console and the graph is not rendered.

package.json

```json
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js'])
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }])
  ]
});
```

graph.js

```js
export const Graph = {
  draw() {
    const Chart = require('char.js');
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

index.html.eex

```html
<div class="phx-hero">
  <h2>Graph: </h2>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<script>require('/js/graph').Graph.draw()</script>
```

I have a phoenix 1.3 project and this is how I use javascript in a template, but it uses brunch. Am I doing this correctly for webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume that you want this to run in all pages. In such case "include" your graph.js in app.js

```
// app.js
import {Graph} from 'graph';
Graph.draw();
```

But if you need this only in specific page, create new "entry" in webpack.config.js

```
// webpack.config.js
entry: {
  './js/app.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js']),
  './js/mypage.js': 'js/mypage.js'
},
```

then type in mypage.js same code as I suggested in first case and then include mypage.js in your page like so:

```
<script src='<%= static_path("js/mypage.js") %>'></script>
```

this line should be added after inclusion of app.js file in layout (I think by default it is included there)

### EDIT

I realised that phoenix default Webpack have hardcoded output, so all js code will still go in same output filename, so below changes must be applied

#### Entry points

```
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js']),
    './js/graph.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/graph.js'])
  },
```

#### Output

note that `'../priv/static/js'` is chnged to `'../priv/static'` and `filename: 'app.js'` is changed to `filename: '[name]'`,

```
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static')
  },
```

#### Plugins

`new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }])` is changed to `new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '' }])`

```
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '' }])
  ]
```

please note that your may be slightly different if you did some changes previously, just pay attention to paths since **output.path** is now one level up in folder structure!

Comment: I want to use it on a single page. I added  `'./js/graph.js': 'js/graph.js'` to my entries section and I added `<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/js/graph.js") %>'></script>` to my template that I want the graph to appear on. I see the error `GET http://localhost:4000/js/graph.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` in the browser.  I am not able to locate the graph.js file in the browser. I think I need to get the graph.js file copied to the browser.

Comment: My fault! you need to change also `output` in webpack.config.js so it respect multi entry patter. Default one will always put everything in app.js. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/

Comment: Yes I needed to edit my webpack config so that the entries and outputs handled the separate file. Thanks!